# Can I have profiler traces for a Java webapp in Azure Application Insights?

Tags: java, azure-application-insights

I am running a Java web app in a VM in Azure. I set up successfully Application Insights for it, and now I am interested to see full call stacks when my web app receives a request, similar to what their docs show [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/profiler-overview#view-profiler-data) for a .NET app.

Is this possible for a Java webapp, the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/profiler-vm) seem too generic to be true?

Answer (score 0):

@lcfd We currently have a Java profiler in private preview (part of Application Insights experience). The only supported platform at the moment is for VMs though we have a way to enable it for Web Apps as well (just not fully supported and tested). Also, since it is in private preview, we do not recommend that you run this is your production environments.

With all that said, if you are still interested, we can help onboard you. Please send a mail to AzCommunity[at]microsoft[dot]com with your subscription ID and a link to this issue.